# No formatting supported by TextField in django admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin-tools

I have Post model and have it registered in admin. It has description of `TextField()`  but while adding new post from admin panel, description area does not support newline or `<br>` or any kind of formatting.

I have no usage of forms and only way to add post is through admin panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks
this reference worked for me.